# Why do I get the warning - "field is never read"

Tags: rust, warnings

I started learning Rust today and I don't get why I've got the warning below:

```
warning: field is never read: `x`
  --> main.rs:62:9
   |
62 |         x: f64, //Float com 64-bits
   |         ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default

warning: field is never read: `y`
  --> main.rs:63:9
   |
63 |         y: f64,
   |         ^^^^^^
```

Here's my code:

```
struct Vec2{
    x: f64, //Float com 64-bits
    y: f64,
}

let v1 = Vec2{x: 1.0, y: 3.0};

let v2 = Vec2{
    x: 14.0,
    ..v1
};

let _v3 = Vec2{ ..v2};

let v4 = Vec2{ x: 3.0, y: 6.0};
let Vec2{x: _, y: _} = v4;
```

As far as I know, I am using x and y, but at the same time, I don't get why I keep getting those dead code warnings. Could someone help?

Comment: Where in the code do you *read* `x` or `y`?

Comment: You can also use [Tuple struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.9.0/book/structs.html#tuple-structs) if you are not explicitly reading field names anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You do not actively read from `x` or `y`.

The `..v1` resp. `..v2` part could easily exist without `y` so rust sees no "real read" there.